# How to Invoke external web service from WSO2 ESB

Tags: web-services, wso2

I want to invoke an external web service from WSO2 ESB, is there any way to do it from the proxy service or something else?

The condition is I have a web service deployed in another computer and I want to invoke that web service from the ESB.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create a proxy service to invoke your web service and get the response back. Please find a sample proxy service[1]. Here the send mediator sends the messages recieved to proxy service to the defined address url. So the uri should be address of your web service. You can define publishWSDL to point the WSDL of your web service. But it is not compulsory. Try out the given sample. You can get a better idea.

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+150%3A+Introduction+to+Proxy+Services

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I'll look for the example u gave :D